# What is a good choice if I wanted daily automated configuration management?

Tags: git, svn

I am doing some development by myself, so I don't have to worry about builds and such, I just want to hack on some code, and have that days code automatically commited.  I only want the files I changed to be updated though and not entire source tree, so what is the easiest way to achieve this?  I am using ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably run a cron job to execute a script.
The script would do something like

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/repo
git add .
git commit -am "Daily commit"
# below line is optional, needed if you want to push to remote repo
# git push master
```

I am not familiar with subversion, the above script will stage the updated files to your branch, commit it ( and optionally push to the remote repo (Github, perhaps ?).